# Azure DevOps Pipeline - To start a VSTS agent interactively from the VSTS job itself for continuous testing

Tags: azure-devops

We have a scenario where we want to run a Telerik scripts from a VSTS job. As a pre-requisite Telerik needs the VSTS agent to be configured as interactive mode. Since it is to configured as interactive, we can not set it as a windows service. So we need to ensure that before the Telerik script is triggered from VSTS pipeline the VSTS agent is also up and running. We can do that manually before firing the Telerik script from VSTS pipeline - and it is working fine when Telerik is invoked after manual set up. But to achieve continuous testing flavour we wanted to integrate the configuration of the VSTS agent (interactive) also from the VSTS pipeline, prior to test execution. But we are having some difficulty here. We see that agent is getting configured with interactive mode but, Telerik script invocation is failing with an error - 
"UNC Path not supported". Any suggestion? Let me know if you need more information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full log? where exactly you get an error?